# David Williams (Prob. with Martingales) Product Spaces Pg 79

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

(1) I completely understand the proof used and how Fubini/Tonelli is applied to prove the alternate formula for $\mathbb{E}[X]$.

My question is what is notation used to define $\mu$. It seems like it is a product of 3 spaces, instead of the only 2 that need to be required.

[A link for the picture of the relevant portion of the text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxSMx.png)

Finally, here are relevant definitions defined earlier in the text. 
$I_{1}^{h}\left(\omega\right) =\int_{\left[0,\infty\right]}\textrm{I}_{A}\left(\omega\right)dx\\
I_{2}^{h}\left(x\right) =\int_{\Omega}\textrm{I}_{A}\left(x\right)d\mathbb{P}\left(\omega\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a product of two measures, P and Lebesgue, on the product space of Omega and the Reals. The extra terms in parentheses are there just to specify the sigma-field of each of these two spaces.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense.